# Files are uploading to Google drive with Untitled name in Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to Google drive using 
    RestAPI in Delphi.Every thing is working fine but files are Uploading into Google drive with Untitled name.

[image]
Below is code i written for uploading into drive.

```
     local_filename:= 'D:/Capture.jpg';
{$ENDIF}
  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.AutoUpdate :=false;
  RESTRequest.Params.Clear;
RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest.AddParameter('application/json; charset=utf-8','{"title": "Capture.jpg"}',TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);

  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2';
  RESTRequest.Resource := '/files?uploadType=multipart';

  upload_stream := TFileStream.Create(local_filename,fmOpenRead);
  upload_stream.Position := 0
 RESTRequest.Addbody(upload_stream, TRESTContentType.ctIMAGE_JPEG);
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

Can some one suggest how to give a file name/ upload the file with the same name to google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Google Drive REST API reference
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads#multipart.
You have to send "metadata". There are 2 options. You complete that simple upload and then call another request to update metada of this file. Or you can do multi-part upload and add a parameter.
This one should work but it seems that REST request does not support this method.

```
RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('metadata', '{"title": "YourFileName.dat"}', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY, [], TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

**So the solution is to update metadata after your request**

```
var
  s: string
RESTRequest1.Response.GetSimpleValue('id', s);

RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+s;
RESTRequest1.Resource := '';
RESTRequest1.Method:=TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
RESTRequest1.AddBody('{"title": "Capture.jpg"}', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddBody()` appears to supercede `AddParameter()`, so you would be wiping out your metadata JSON. This is stated in the [`AddBody()` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddBody):

> Generally, **a call to AddBody replaces any previous value of the body parameter**. However, if you pass ABodyContent as a string, the specified value is appended, and the resulting request contains several body parameters

The JSON metadata and the JPG file need to be sent together in the request body, in `multipart/related` format.  However, looking at `TRESTRequest`, I don't see an easy way to send requests in that format (I may be wrong here). You might have to put the entire `multipart` data in a single `TStream` and pass that to `AddBody()` with a ContentType of `TRESTContentType.ctMULTIPART_RELATED`.  If you try to add the various pieces as separate parameters, it won't send the right content type:

> A single-parameter request uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded, while **a multiple-parameter request uses multipart/mixed instead**.